# How do I update SP2010's database version?

Tags: migration, content-database

I currently am in middle of migrating sharepoint 2010 site to another server. My current version of SharePoint server database says:

> Database Schema Versions
>   Microsoft.SharePoint.Upgrade.SPContentDatabaseSequence Current Schema
>   Version: 4.0.145.0,  Maximum Schema Version: 4.1.10.0
>
> Microsoft.SharePoint.Upgrade.SPContentDatabaseSequence2 Current Schema
>   Version: 4.0.8.0,
>
> Maximum Schema Version: 4.1.3.0
>
> Microsoft.SharePoint.Administration.SPContentDatabase Current Schema
>   Version: 
>   14.0.4762.1000, Maximum Schema Version: 14.0.6112.5000

But the destination server says:

> Configuration Database version  14.0.6112.5000
>
> Content Database
>
> ->SPContentDatabaseSequence – Current: 4.1.10.0  Max: 4.1.10.0
>
> ->SPContentDatabaseSequence2 – Current: 4.1.3.0  Max: 4.1.3.0
>
> ->SPContentDatabase – Current: 14.0.6112.5000  Max: 14.0.6112.5000

How do I update my first server to meet requirement of second server?

I know that we have to install a patch. Where would I find it? Could you also please explain the precautions I should take before I update the database of my SharePoint server?

Comment: For reference, the first version 14.0.4762.1000, is RTM and the second version, 14.0.6112.5000 is the October 2011 CU

Answer (score 1):

Here's the official page with the list of the last updates: http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/ff800847.aspx#LatestUpdates. here's the whitepaper on the SharePoint patching process practices: http://www.microsoft.com/download/en/details.aspx?displaylang=en&id=24859. And if you open a description for any update from the official page I gave above you'll find a note about its build version. For example if you open December 2011 Update for SharePoint Foundation [page](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2597058) you'll see the note:

> This is build 14.0.6114.5000 of the cumulative update package.

Answer (score 1):

I had trouble understanding your question

I assume that you are doing this:

- I have a newer SharePoint 2010 farm with a higher patch level
- I have content databases that may be from an older patch level
- I need to attach these content databases to my new SP 2010 farm

If that is the case then:

Mount the old SP Content database in the new farm (using powershell)

```
mount-spcontentdatabase
```

Full syntax here:

[TechNet: Attach or detach content databases (SharePoint Server 2010)](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff628582)

Mounting the database will automatically upgrade the database as part of mounting it.  If errors occur during the mount you can use:

```
Test-SPContentDatabase
Upgrade-SPContentDatabase
```

[TechNet: Test-SPContentDatabase](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff607941.aspx)

[TechNet: Upgrade-SPContentDatabase](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff607813.aspx)

You may also want to upgrade the farm:

```
psconfig.exe -cmd upgrade -inplace v2v -wait
```

[TechNet: Command-line reference for the SharePoint Products and Technologies Configuration Wizard (Office SharePoint Server)](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc263093%28v=office.12%29.aspx)